# Opening a menu by pressing a key

Tags: jquery, menu

Okay so I have a menu on top.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function()
{
jQuery(".clickMeToOpenMenu").toggle(function()
{ 
jQuery('#menu').stop().animate({'height':'500px'},500)
},function()
{
jQuery('#menu').stop().animate({'height':'0px'},500)
});
```

So this works perfectly fine, the menu slides down then I click on it.

**Now my question is I want the menu to be opened just pressing a key (`CTRL`) .**

```
jQuery('body, html').live('keypress', openMenu)
});
function openMenu(e)
{
if(e.keyCode == '17') // KEY 17 = CTRL
{
e.preventDefault()
jQuery('.clickMeToOpenMenu').trigger('click');
}
}
```

Putting "`jQuery('.clickMeToOpenMenu').trigger('click');`" in console works fine and opens the menu how ever when I press `CTRL` nothing happends.

Comment: `live` is depricated btw

Comment: this maybe of some help: `https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event.ctrlKey`

Comment: Please add relevant HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `keydown` event to cath ctrl key event

```
jQuery('body, html').on('keydown', openMenu)

function openMenu(e) {
  console.log(e.keyCode)
  if (e.keyCode == '17') // KEY 17 = CTRL
  {
    e.preventDefault()
    jQuery('.clickMeToOpenMenu').trigger('click');
  }
}
```

LIVE EXEMPLE (alert box when ctrl key is pressed) : http://jsfiddle.net/YbJ2q/29/show/

source http://jsfiddle.net/YbJ2q/29/

Comment: Thanks for the help so far, the console sees me hitting the key but the menu isn't sliding out.

I guess I made a mistake in the function 'openMenu' ?
The weird thing is, copy pasting jQuery('.clickMeToOpenMenu').trigger('click'); in console works.

Comment: The way you simulate the click on the menu is correct. You could try to move the prevent default statement after the menu call. If it is not working, add an alert message in the click event of your menu and check or go through using step by step function (F12, then script, find the line and click on the line number to add a debug point)

Answer (score -1):

You can't use `CTRL` key alone in `keypress`, as it is a modifier key.

Try `keydown` instead.